# Wubi installation

Tags: wubi

I have downloaded Ubuntu beta 2 for installation. But cant get it right cause installation goes inside windows with wubi and when restarting fails to continue and I'm using Benq joyBook 7000 please cause it has been like these from the Alpha releases while 10.04 was working pretty I must say it had to disable req 11 first, I'm afraid the final release might not work too. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing F8 when Ubuntu boots and choose the "ACPI compatibility mode". Might help Ubuntu to interact with your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows? If it's win7 you can resize the NTFS in Windows very easily and install a TRUE Ubuntu to the free space. If it isn't then the installer can resize NTFS too. Be sure your backups are up to date in case of catastrophe and for god's sake run on the mains power when you do it.

This will not only give you a faster OS (Wubi uses a file on crappy NTFS as the Ubuntu drive), but is also drastically simpler to fix if things go wrong as you can very easily use the live CD to access the partitions.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus